# Auto scaling Azure App Service by Queue Length

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-app-service-plans

Is there currently a way to autoscale an Azure App Service plan by a "v2" storage account message queue? When I attempt to set up autoscaling based on a message queue, it is only showing my "classic" storage accounts. I would prefer to not destroy and recreate the storage account as classic just because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently that supports classic storage accounts only. I would suggest you to provide feedback here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites